# Simple react hook always one step back

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning react in framer.
Just do basic stuff before move forward and I noticed one issue.

```
import { createStore } from "https://framer.com/m/framer/store.js@^1.0.0"

const MainStore = createStore({
    TestVar: 0,
})

export function ButtonTap(Comp): ComponentType {
    return (props) => {
        var [CurrentVar, setCurrentVar] = MainStore()

        return (
            <Comp
                {...props}
                onClick={() => {
                    setCurrentVar({ TestVar: CurrentVar.TestVar + 1 })
                    console.log(CurrentVar.TestVar)
                }}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Basically this ButtonTap is adding onClick function.

**The question is** why on first click I dont get result in console of 1 (0+1) but i get 0. Feels like I get previous result on click.

Answer (score 0):

As setState operations are async in nature for optimization purpose, react try to bulk update.
You can use callBack to update the state which guarantees the setState will get the previous value

```
setCurrentVar((prevState,props)=>{return { TestVar: prevState.TestVar + 1 }})
```

Comment: But I don't need previous State, I need current. But it returns previous (even with my example code)